# Webforms and Groups Modules Interactions

Tags: webforms, group

I have [webforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and [groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) modules installed - [based on webform documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/3098093) my understanding is if I:

1. Create a webform with an entity relationship field to a content type = blog
2. Group A has 3 unpublished blogs: A, B, and C (all unique Node IDs)
3. Group B has 5 unpublished blogs: 1, 2, 3, 4, and A (all unique Node IDs)

The the following scenarios:

1. User in Group A will see Blogs to select with A, B, and C
2. User in Group B will see Blogs to select with 1, 2, 3, 4 and A
3. User Not in either group - will see nothing :)
4. User In both groups will see them all.

Am I understanding this correctly - i.e., permissions from groups are preserved by webform module.

Thanks!  Adam